# Hard drive showing more disk space usage than is actually being used

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server

I am running Windows Server 2012 R2. My C drive reports that 420 GB are being used, but I can't figure out what's using all that space. WinDirStat (which I "Ran as administrator") and selecting all the folders in Windows Explorer reports 49.4 GB being used. I don't think it's shadow copies because I've disabled it for that disk and when I run `vssadmin list shadows /for=C:`, it reports that "No items were found that satisfy the query". I've also defragged it and run disk cleanup. What could be using that space?

Comment: WinDirStat can only profile what folders and files it can access.

Comment: Windows Explorer reports the same.

Comment: Windows Explorer runs at the same permission level as the user who is logged in.  If you don't have acces to even view a folder/file it wont be listed in a Windows explorer window.

Comment: What should I use then to get a more accurate profile?

Comment: You should run the application, as a user, who is in a group that can access all files and folders.  We can't tell you what that is, on your server, every server is configured differently.

Comment: I've run both as Administrator which should be able to see everything.

Comment: Have you tried running TreeSize Professional as an administrator? It counts all files (regardless of permissions). You can download the demo here: 
http://www.jam-software.com/treesize/

Comment: TreeSize Professional found what it was. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Right click WinDirStat and selcet `Run as Administrator`.  This will allow the program to access the directories and files it didnt have permission to by default.

Comment: I did that when I ran it.